# Devise forgot password when nested

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

My Rails 5 app running on Heroku uses Devise for auth and it is currently nested. Looks like this in routes.rb:

```
resources :teams do
  member do
    get :about
    get :foundation
  end

  devise_for :users, :path_prefix => 'auth',
  :controllers => {
    :masquerades => "admin/masquerades",
    :registrations => "registrations",
    :sessions => "sessions",
    :password => "passwords"
  }
```

When I try to set up forgot password I get error after error with wrong routes because all standards from devise will point to `new_user_session_path` and not `new_user_team_session_path`.

Currently I get this error: `undefined method new_user_session_path for <ActionDispatch::Routing::RoutesProxy:0x007fd6e50b1328>`

My idea has been to generate the devise views and controllers and fix all the links. However, the current error does not appear in the passwords controller I took from the source: `https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/passwords_controller.rb`

My problem is this: I want to add a 'Reset password' feature and have nested Devise routes. How do I solve this?

EDIT:

Here is output from `rake routes`:

```
new_user_team_session         GET    /auth/users/teams/:team_id/sign_in(.:format)                             sessions#new
user_team_session             POST   /auth/users/teams/:team_id/sign_in(.:format)                             sessions#create
destroy_user_team_session     DELETE /auth/users/teams/:team_id/sign_out(.:format)                            sessions#destroy
new_user_team_password        GET    /auth/users/teams/:team_id/password/new(.:format)                        devise/passwords#new
edit_user_team_password       GET    /auth/users/teams/:team_id/password/edit(.:format)                       devise/passwords#edit
user_team_password            PATCH  /auth/users/teams/:team_id/password(.:format)                            devise/passwords#update
                              PUT    /auth/users/teams/:team_id/password(.:format)                            devise/passwords#update
                              POST   /auth/users/teams/:team_id/password(.:format)                            devise/passwords#create
cancel_user_team_registration GET    /auth/users/teams/:team_id/cancel(.:format)                              registrations#cancel
   new_user_team_registration GET    /auth/users/teams/:team_id/sign_up(.:format)                             registrations#new
  edit_user_team_registration GET    /auth/users/teams/:team_id/edit(.:format)                                registrations#edit
       user_team_registration PATCH  /auth/users/teams/:team_id(.:format)                                     registrations#update
                              PUT    /auth/users/teams/:team_id(.:format)                                     registrations#update
                              DELETE /auth/users/teams/:team_id(.:format)                                     registrations#destroy
                              POST   /auth/users/teams/:team_id(.:format)                                     registrations#create
back_user_team_masquerade_index GET    /auth/users/teams/:team_id/masquerade/back(.:format)                     admin/masquerades#back
user_team_masquerade          GET    /auth/users/teams/:team_id/masquerade/:id(.:format)                      admin/masquerades#show
```

Cheers

Comment: What is the output of `rake routes`? This `:path_prefix => 'auth'` must be doing the magic.

Comment: Here is output of rake routes: https://pastebin.com/tCg73qFE

Comment: Can you add it to the question itself?

Comment: Added the output from rake routes.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I'd be happy to jump on codementor and post the results here after.